# Adding Google Places search box on page

Tags: search, box

I have embedded a simple google map with the stores I needed located on them. I would like to add a search box just above the map in the center or in the map at the top as per the places search box. Really not sure on whats the best method of this as my html is very limited.

this is my map code

```
<section class="mbr-section mbr-section__container" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 80px;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="mbr-map"><iframe frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1Dt00Nkp6QbZ3DqYkrR7NCjTSQyo"></iframe></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```